# Can LINQ return a nested set of objects?

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have a hierarchical Object Structure:

```
Parent
List(of Child)

Child
List (of SubChild)
```

Is it possible to get every single SubChild from Parent (as a new list), using LINQ (preferably using Lambda)?

Traditionally it would be done inside a loop:

```
Foreach(Child in Parent)
.. Foreach(SubChild in Child)
.... Add SubChild to FullSubChildList
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Enumerable.SelectMany`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany(v=vs.100).aspx) to project and flatten hierarchy:

```
var FullSubChildList = 
    Parent.SelectMany(p => p.ChildList).SelectMany(c => c.SubChildList).ToList();
```

If Parent is `IEnumerable<Child>` and Child is `IEnumerable<SubChild>` (according to your code sample):

```
var FullSubChildList = Parent.SelectMany(p => p).SelectMany(c => c).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use SelectMany to do this:

```
parent.SelectMany(p => p.Child.SelectMany(c => c.SubChild))
      .Select(...)
```